# Meet-irreducible element of lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I have a question concerning the exercise 5.7 of the Davey & Priestley's book. Here are the questions:

Let $L$ be a finite distributive lattice. Prove by the steps below that $\mathcal{J}(L)\cong\mathcal{M}(L)$.

(i) Let $x\in\mathcal{J}(L)$. Show that there exists $\hat{x}\in L$ such that $\downarrow \hat{x}=L\backslash\uparrow x$. [Hint. Let $\hat{x}:=\bigvee (L\backslash\uparrow x)$ and then use Lemma 5.11 to show that $\hat{x}\not\geq x$].

> > I have done it and it's ok.

(ii) Show that for all $x\in\mathcal{J}(L)$ the element $\hat{x}$ defined in (i) is meet-irreducible.

> > Here, I would need some help. We have to show that if $\bigvee (L\backslash\uparrow x)<a$ and $\bigvee (L\backslash\uparrow x)<b$ then $\bigvee (L\backslash\uparrow x)<a\wedge b$. 
> >     Can we show first that: 
> >     $\forall y\in L\backslash\uparrow x$ if $y<a$ and $y<b$ then $y<a\wedge b$

Thank you.

Comment: What is J,M and V?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\mathcal{J}(L)$ is the set of join-irreducible elements, $\mathcal{M}(L)$ is the set of meet-irreducible elements, $\bigvee S$ is the join of all elements in a set $S$. These are fairly standard notations, although the OP probably could've explained them.

Answer (score 2):

Relating to your question 
"Can we show first that...": no, that's not true.
As an example, take $L$ to be the power-set of $\{a,b,c\}$, which is distributive.
Singletons are join-irreducible. For example, take $x=\{a\}$; $y=\{b\} \in L\setminus\uparrow x$.
Then $y=\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}$, so it is not meet-irreducible.

Now, for the main problem: prove that $\hat{x}$ is meet-irreducible.
Suppose, for a contradiction, that it isn't, that is, there exist $a,b\in L$ such that $\hat{x}=a \wedge b$, but $x\neq a,b$ (and so $x<a$ and $x<b$).
So $a,b \notin \downarrow\hat{x}=L\setminus\uparrow x$, and thus $a,b \in \uparrow x$, that is, $x\leq a$ and $x \leq b$.
It follows that $x\leq a\wedge b =\hat{x}$, a contradiction to what you have proved in (i) (that $\hat{x}\ngeq x$).

Comment: On thank you. By the way, the definition of meet-irreducible is:
$\forall a, \forall b, x<a\wedge x<b\Longrightarrow x<a\wedge b$. So the negation should be: $\exists a, \exists b, x<a\wedge x<b\mbox{ and } x\not<a\wedge b$. However, how can we deduce from this that it is equivalent to $\exists a, \exists b, x<a\wedge x<b\mbox{ and } x=a\wedge b$

Comment: I mean, the order is partial and not total.

Comment: @pierre If $x \leq a$ and $x \leq b$, then certainly $x\leq a \wedge b$. So, in that case, if $x\not< a\wedge b$, it follows that $x=a\wedge b$.