# Down set as irreducible set of a lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I posted recently a question on meet-irreducible sets. (cf below) I have a similar question here:

Let $P$ be a finite ordered set. Show that a down-set $U$ is meet-irreducible in $\mathcal{O}(P)$ if and only if it is of the form $P\backslash\uparrow x$ for some $x\in P$.

As for $x$, i would like to choose something like: $x=\bigvee\{V\in \mathcal{O}(P),U⊆V\}$. 
The class of sets $\{V\in \mathcal{O}(P),U⊆V\}$ is (I think) a filter. Is this information relevant? My idea is to find an $x$ such that it is a supremium of a family of sets that cover $U$

What do you think of my x? Not sure if its the right answer, but I think it is close to it.

link to previous post:
[Meet-irreducible element of lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755777/meet-irreducible-element-of-lattice/2756380?noredirect=1#comment5687354_2756380)

Comment: What is $\mathcal O(P)$ ?

Comment: Your first guess (that $U$ is meet-irreducible iff $U=P\setminus\uparrow x$) seems to be fine. The other one seems completely off. Notice that $P\in\{V\in\mathcal O(P):U\subseteq V\}$, and so the join if this set is $P$. I should think the solution would come from $$U=P\setminus\uparrow x \Leftrightarrow P\setminus U=\uparrow x \Leftrightarrow x=\bigwedge(P\setminus U).$$

Comment: @jcdornano It's the set (lattice) of order-ideals of $P$ (that is, [downsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) of $P$).

Comment: that"s very interesting. It's a general fact that:   $E=\uparrow x\Longleftrightarrow x=\bigwedge E$?

Comment: @pierre No it isn't. For example, in $A=\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\geq 1\}$, with the usual order, $0=\bigwedge\{1/n:n\geq 1\}$, but $\uparrow 0 = A$.

Comment: Here, the lattice is not finite. But when it's finite:
$E=\uparrow x\Longleftrightarrow x=\bigwedge E$